# Uploading file in Selenium using sendKeys() is not working

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, webdriver, sendkeys

I am unable to upload files using `sendKeys()`. This is my code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(Locators.browseFlagIconBtn)).sendKeys("D:\\Images\\icons.png");
```

I have an input tag of type file for file upload

```
<input type="file" id="iconFlagFile" name="iconFile" onchange="setFlagIconFile()" value="" class=" file-input-opacity" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; font-size: 200px; line-height: 200px; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0;">
```

However when I click on submit button of the form where this input field is then I am redirected to the below page:

[image]

Cause of this issue :

When I pass the path using `sendKeys()` then it correctly picks up the file that needs to be uploaded. However, the actual upload takes place when user clicks on the submit button. Now I don't know why it it searches for the file that it picked in Chrome's directory, for example: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\53.0.2785.116"`

Obviously it will not be able to find the file.

Question: How to fix this? Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following javascript executor code

```
String filePath = "D:\\Images\\icons.png";
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsx.executeScript("document.getElementById('iconFlagFile').value='" + filePath + "';");
```

Comment: If that doesn't work then try the following:



`JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('iconFlagFile').style.display = 'block';");


driver.findElement(By.id("iconFlagFile")).sendKeys("D:\\Images\\icons.png");
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('iconFlagFile').style.display = 'none';");`

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, I am assuming that, you have an HTML tag that allows you to upload a file from local drive but it is not enabled. Unless you hit submit button it wont allow you to upload a file.

In such case, try to edit the form tag to edit and then try to call sendKeys() method, and you can edit the html elements using javascript executor

Comment: It would be nice to put html code of the element where you want to put the path, is it of input file type.?

Comment: I have added the html code. I have an input tag of type file for uploading files

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for file upload.

```
    String filename = "path of the file";
    File file = new File(filename);
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    // give the URL to upload
    driver.findElement(By locator).sendKeys(path);
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried this. Actual file upload takes place when the user clicks on the submit button and not when the file is selected in File Upload Box. So unfortunately the solution given by you is not working in my case. :(

Comment: @UbaidAhmed Can you please post the actual exception

Comment: I am not getting any exception. Please refer the screenshot attached. I am providing the path of D:\ but when I am submitting the form it is looking for the file in C:\.

When I perform the same steps manually then it is working fine. Problem arises when it is done via automation.

Comment: @UbaidAhmed This works in every case where input type is a File. I dont have much of your data to test from my end. But can you please try again by changing locator from 'xpath' to either 'name' or 'id' and using path as a String variable only.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Clipboard class and Robot class combination**

```
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    StringSelection str = new StringSelection("File Path");
    clipboard.setContents(str, null);

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("elementXpath"));
    element.click();

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    driverwait(1);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    driverwait(1);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```